# What do levels really mean?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I picked up a copy of Injustice: Gods Among Us recently, and played some single player while waiting for my wife to get home.

When she did, we launched a multiplayer game (both signing in with our Live accounts).  She was really upset when she looked at my tag in the corner and saw 'level 11'.

She comes from a strong RPG background, and she went into the battle thinking she had no chance against me 'since I was so much higher in level'.

I managed to convince her, finally, that the displayed level was an account thing, which didn't affect my character's abilities, health, or damage.  It may have been easier if I hadn't thoroughly destroyed her in the first few matches.

It did get me wondering what the level actually means.  I know I get a few bits of in-game currency for unlocking costumes and music each time I gain a level, but is that all they do?

Comment: Side note: I don't have the rep to create the 'injustice' tag...could someone do that for me?

Comment: This question probably isn't limited to only the 360, so I've removed the other tags.  If it turns out it is, feel free to re-add it.

Comment: @fbueckert: Thanks!  I couldn't create the tag it deserved, so I tagged it as well as I could.

Comment: I can't take credit for creating the tag; all I did was clean it up.  Thank @ObliviousSage for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the XP system in the console versions of the game is largely just for show. It will unlock things like character skins and concept art once you hit certain levels, but it's all extra or aesthetic based unlocks. Mortal Kombat had a similar coin (*or should I say koin?*) system that allowed players to unlock things like the button combinations to enter to perform a fatality. With your levels you should unlock Armory Keys that can be used in the Archives to specifically select what things you want.

Comment: How kould you even think about saying 'coin'?  I kan't konceive of a more khuckle-worthy think to konsider saying when discussing such a klassic franchise as Mortal Kombat.